# XLNET how to deal with text with more than 512 tokens?

Tags: bert, text-classification

From what I searched online, XLNET model is pre-trained with 512 tokens, and https://github.com/zihangdai/xlnet/issues/80 , I didn't find too much useful information on that either.
How does XLnet outperform BERT on long text when the max_sequence_length hyperparameter is less than 1024 tokens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BERT also [has the same limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58636587/674487) of 512 tokens.

Normally, for longer sequences, you just truncate to 512 tokens.

The limit is derived from the positional embeddings in the Transformer architecture, for which a maximum length needs to be imposed. The magnitude of such a size is related to the amount of memory needed to handle texts: attention layers scale quadratically with the sequence length, which poses a problem with long texts.

There are new architectures that specifically deal with longer sequences, like [Longformer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.05150.pdf), [Reformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04451), [Big Bird](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.14062) and [Linformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04768).