# How can models like Mosaic's MPT-7b or Bloombergs BLOOMGPT take in so many tokens?

Tags: language-model

I've read the paper on [ALiBi](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.12409.pdf), and I understand that these models are biasing the values made in the query/key multiplication.

But from my understanding, when I build the actual model I give it `N` input nodes. When I train a model I give it vectors of length `N`. How then at inference can I give it vectors of length greater than `N`? Am I misunderstanding how the multiplication of key and query works? Can there be keys of any length?

Edit: I guess my question includes, why isn't there a multiplication error when I use longer keys in my inference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the attention blocks, Keys and Values are of the same length, but Queries are not necessarily of the same length as the former. For instance, in the encoder-decoder attention blocks, the Keys and Values come from the encoder representations while the Queries come from the decoder representations (which are computed from a completely different sequence than the encoder ones).

In the Transformer model, the only factor limiting the length of the inputs is the positional embeddings (see [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/120602/14675) for details. In the ALiBi paper, they replace them with a non-trainable approach and, experimentally, the approach is shown to extrapolate to longer sequences than those seen during training.